# I am finally hired as a programmer. But I know "nothing"

Tags: work-environment, work-experience, developer

I've finally got my first opportunity as a PHP web developer. The thing is: I know very, very little PHP. I studied programming logic while I was in college, I've always worked with IT infrastructure, but only three months as a PHP developer six years ago. I also learned OOP with Java. Well, I know I'm not completely noob at coding, but I know I'm light years away from full-time developers. They hired me despite me being clear enough by saying I know very, very little of PHP. Again: the hired me. I'm very happy but somewhat insecure.

What would you recommend to me, in order to to accelerate my learning process? Considering I was hired and immediately kicked into the frontline haha

By the way, I've just had my second day at the office, and I'm still struggling with  GIT, which I'm not familiarized with, at all.

Comment: It is normal that new topics tend to be hard to get into without a good introduction. (This equally applies to research topics, etc.) - Every field has its own language, its own habit and some views will seem downright bizarre to people "on the outside". Sometimes it is different culture - sometimes "broken by design" because someone thought it would be a good idea.... With time it gets better.

Comment: @DetlevCM yeah. Maybe I'm just freaking out for nothing. After all, we humans were born to adapt new environments. We got the potential for that. And of course, I believe in God. In my case, faith counts a lot

Comment: If you weren't lost at your first job on day 2, something would be wrong.  It takes time for anyone to jump into an established codebase, especially early in their career.  You're right where you should be.  And really you don't need to know most of git-  you can do 99% of your job with about 5 commands you can write down-  git checkout, git pull, git push, git add, and git commit.  Everything else you google when you need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's absolutely okay to struggle with Git. I think I only sort of figured it out after about a year of using it full-time, and that's me using source control systems for 12+ years previous. A few years on, I'm very comfortable with it, but still have to google some rare corner cases.

As to getting familiar with PHP, like with anything else, there's nothing better than regular practice. Upskill by writing your own code, by asking people to review it, by looking at their code. Check out edx.org or udemy.com for any courses specifically on PHP and server-side scripting in general.

There's many rewards for curious programmers, so **stay curious and you will learn and improve**.

Comment: Hey , pal! Well, some other people have just told the same as you regarding GIT. And considering your experience with that, i feel more relaxed by reading it hehe. Curiosity is something I have (I think that's why I've chosen to work with IT). I've been wandering on the last days if I could develop something ,at home, to help me out with anything in my routine... I'll take your advice seriously.

Comment: @user10847903 Most developers I know of have a pet project they work on at home to help keep their skills sharp

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf yeah, I'm thinking about what kind of pet will help me at home hehe

Comment: You can do something mundane like solving puzzles in PHP (see https://projecteuler.net/), or you could build something out of your own passion (this one always worked better for me), so, say, you are very interested in cars, then build a website about cars. PHP is mostly about websites, so websites is the category you'd have to think in. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Latch on to one of the senior developers. Ask them what their best practice of Git is (including what environments and branches are in use - you don't want to be committing changes to the production branch accidentally)

Ask the senior developer to assign you issues from the project task list. Use these to gain familiarity with the project. Ask the seniors for code reviews of your work, and in the quiet times, be on Lynda (or whatever your company provides).

Your company won't expect you to hit the ground running - but they also want to see some positive action on your part. Don't sit and wait for things to come to you.

Comment: This is one of my strategies at this moment: keep on moving. I believe it counts a lot. Never heard of Lynda. Thanks ,pal. I'll check it.

Comment: Here in Brazil I use Alura. It's a great learning plataform. I would recommend to the others but they don't have any courses in English.